# can't make a custom dice roller it says ("non-integer stop for randrange()")

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to make a custom dice roller

it says "("non-integer stop for randrange()")"

```
import random

sides = input("Sides")
custom = random.randrange(1, sides) #see here
```

please help me please
the problem is with the custom integer
the integer is chosen but python doesn't like the range to be
chosen by the person what should I do instead

Comment: Your input is a string. Convert it with `int()` into an integer, `random.randrange(1, int(sides))` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

sides = input("Sides")
if isinstance(sides, str) and sides.isdigit():
    sides = int(sides)
    # Ensure value to be greater than lower range i.e 1 else a traceback
    if sides > 1:
        custom = random.randrange(1, sides) #see here
```